# What is up with jQuery Nivo Slider on my site?

Tags: jquery, magento, slider

I have installed the Nivo Slider (http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) that uses jQuery on my site which is a Magento ecommerce site.

My site is http://bikeshop.gostorego.com/

Any ideas why on the homepage you can see where the slider goes, but the loading icon is only present not showing the slides?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery isn't being loaded on the page.

This is how you're attempting to load it:

```
<script src=’https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js’ type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Firebug shows that this URL is what's actually being requested:

http://bikeshop.gostorego.com/%E2%80%99https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js%E2%80%99

So, those unusual quotes are the problem; you need normal single or double quotes:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @thirtydot - I just edited the quotes and still doesn't seem to be working for some reason.

Comment: I was trying to fix this, but it's rather confusing because your files keep changing. I did have it working at one point, but something changed. Don't lose hope, it is possible :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note while using Nivo Slider with Mangeto (due to prototype library) is to use as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery.fn._reverse = []._reverse; //this is very important
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        jQuery('#slider').nivoSlider({
            //...
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you want a ready made Nivo Slider Extension which works great with Magento having ability to add unlimited no of groups and slides anywhere in frontend easily, then you can use following extension (jQuery Sliders Pro):
http://www.magepsycho.com/jquery-sliders-pro-nivo-slider.html

Happy E-Commerce!!